# Google Vision API - Analyse a sequence of images

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, google-cloud-vision

Let me expose you the problem :

I'm currently developing on Visual Studio Community 2017 edition.
I made a Windows Form that analyse content of an image with the Google API. I managed to make it work for 1 single picture, so the process is : 
I start the program, the Windows appears, I press the button " Analyse image" and then it prints the result of the Label Detection in a TextBox.

This part works great.

But now, I would like to analyse all images of a file, so I started with 5 images, just to try. 
So I made a foreach loop, and renamed my pictures with "1.jpg", "2.jpg", etc... up to "5.jpg". 
Here's the code :

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        textBox1.Text = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            int number = i;
            textBox1.Text = "Image number : " + number + "\r\n";

            var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\sequence\\" + number + ".jpg");
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);

            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
            }
            textBox1.Text = "Next image processing.... \r\n";
        }
    }
```

And when I press the " Analyse Button " ( Button1 ), the program prints 
"Image 1 :"
Then I have to wait a few seconds, and then it prints " Next image processing...", and it never prints anything more.

So any ideas ? 
Is it because I have to clear the TextBox to re-write in it ?

Anyone knows my problem ? :(

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any major technical issue here.
Few observations:
client creation is better done once out of the for loop. No need to create an instance of it again and again.
while assigning the text it's better to do += 
From your reference code, the end result in text will always be "Next image processing..."
However, if you think the code is not getting executed for next value of i = 2, which is unlikely from the code.
You could debug it to atleast ensure, its getting called or not.
I did in my environment with my own instance of the ImageAnnotatorClient. Below representation of your code works perfectly for me.
Hope this helps

```
            textBox1.Text = "";
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {

                    int number = i;
                    textBox1.Text += "Image number : " + number + "\r\n";

                    var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\sequence\\" + number + ".jpg");

                    var response = client.DetectLabels(image);

                    foreach (var annotation in response)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
                    }
                    textBox1.Text += "Next image processing.... \r\n";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```